# Map returns array with undefined values

Tags: javascript, json, map-function

I want to remove properties `_id` and `__v` from Mongo result (which is array with markers) with map, but I always get array with `null` values in JSON result instead of array with objects without this two properties.

```
Marker.find().then(result => {
    const markers = result.map(marker => {
        delete marker['_id'];
        delete marker['__v'];
    });
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ markers: markers }));
}).catch(next);
```

This is how returned JSON looks *without* mapping:

```
{
    "markers": [
        {
            "_id": "5a7e266b6d7f6d00147bc269",
            "id": "da27cbf8372aaeb24ce20a21",
            "x": "25",
            "y": "37",
            "timestamp": 2093355239,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5a7e2789c61cf90014d67e6b",
            "id": "5580d237f486088499c6d82k",
            "x": "56",
            "y": "29",
            "timestamp": 2138203308,
            "__v": 0
        },
    ]
}
```

This is how returned JSON looks *with* mapping:

```
{
    "markers": [
        null,
        null
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, it is prettified JSON from Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. None of given solutions have worked because the problem was about Mongoose. Data returned by Mongoose is `MongooseDocument` and is not editable. I just had to add [`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) method in query to get the editable result. After that, I used Icepickle's solution.

```
Marker.find().lean().then(result => {
  const markers = result.map(marker => {
    const { ['_id']: _, ['__v']: __, ...rest } = marker;
    return rest;
  });
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ markers: markers }));
}).catch(next);
```

Comment: Where do you use the `lean()` in your process workflow (so that other might use it in the future)?

Comment: @Icepickle Oops, I forgot to add it in example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return something in your map function.
The map function returns a new array containing what you return from your map function. If you return nothing it is undefined.

```
Marker.find().then(result => {
    const markers = result.map(marker => {
        delete marker['_id'];
        delete marker['__v'];
        return marker;
    });
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ markers: markers }));
}).catch(next);
```

Comment: Doesn't this also mutate the original object (items returned from `Marker.find()`)?

Comment: @Caramiriel As far as I know, map function is immutable. For some reason, this properties are still not deleted, although I **do** get them now.

Comment: @Nikola _“map function is immutable”_ — that’s not the point. You’re mutating the `result` object within `map`, which is something you should use `forEach` for, instead. Alternatively, you could `map` each `marker` to a _new_ object, not containing `_id` and `__v`; this way you don’t mutate `result`.

Comment: @Xufox I understand that. I misunderstood his comment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting (and essentially mutating your result array), you could consider the following

```
Marker.find().then(result => {
  const markers = result.map(marker => {
    const { ['_id']: _, ['__v']: __, ...rest } = marker;
    return rest;
  });
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ markers: markers }));
}).catch(next);
```

which would use destructuring to create a copy of the marker, ommitting the 2 properties that you have previously deleted. So `_` would contain the value for `_id` and `__` would contain the value for `__V`, the remaining part of your object would be contained inside the `rest` variable

Comment: Very elegant solution, thanks. For those who don't know; you need to Node 8 to use spread syntax (I got `SyntaxError` when I tried to use this example because I had `6.9.2`). However, this example makes objects full with other things - `$__`, `isNew` and `$init` properties and doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Nikola It makes a full copy that is true, if you just want specific things then you should rather name the things you do want to receive using destructuring. You are right about Node 8, since this is part of the ES7 destructuring syntax

Comment: I don't really understand things now. I thought this should return whole object without `_id` and `__v` property, but instead it returns object with `$__`, `isNew` and `$init` (probably meta informations) along with `_id` and `__v` **too** in `_doc` property. I know how destructuring works, but that would make whole solution (considering the nesting level) so big that it would be easier to just make new object and assign only properties I need to it's properties.

Comment: @Nikola that is probably the meta data from your mongo handling, why not get the `marker._doc` and distruct that one?

Comment: you don't understand me. I can do that, but the `_doc` has literally the same structure as currently returned object. What would I do after I get it? That's like solving the same problem twice.

Comment: @Nikola, alright, but that you would have with your original code or the currently highest upvoted answer as well, mine doesn't do anything else as far as I know

Comment: no, your solution is actually very elegant and helpful. I solved the problem now, see my answer on the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Key value pairs can be filtered in the [`JSON.stringify` replacer parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) :

```js
o = {"markers":[{"_id":"5a7e266b6d7f6d00147bc269","id":"da27cbf8372aaeb24ce20a21","x":"25","y":"37","timestamp":2093355239,"__v":0},{"_id":"5a7e2789c61cf90014d67e6b","id":"5580d237f486088499c6d82k","x":"56","y":"29","timestamp":2138203308,"__v":0}]}

j = JSON.stringify(o, (k, v) => k[0] === '_' ? void 0 : v, 2)

console.log(j)
```